# IBM Worklight - How to configure URL element of a SQL adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have an application that retrieves data from a database using a SQL adapter.

This is my scenario: a machine which could be like a "server" in which there is the database and a device which could be the "client". If I have a LAN in which both machine and device are connected, how must i set the `adapter.xml` to connect to the machine?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2012. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="DbConnect"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:sql="http://www.worklight.com/integration/sql">

    <displayName>DbConnect</displayName>
    <description>DbConnect</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>mysql</password>
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
    </connectivity>

    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="remoteDbSize"/>
    <procedure name="getCanti"/>
    <procedure name="getCategorie"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

I suppose I change the `<url>` value and instead of `localhost` I must edit it with the IP address on LAN of machine. Is it right? Would be interesting also know how it works if I want to connect to a remote machine, a real server in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the backend is local or remote, does not matter.

If you intend to use SQL adapters in order to connect to a SQL backend, the URL element in the adapter XML is required to point to that database, not just to the IP address of the server hosting the database.

Example: `<url>jdbc:mysql://my-host-or-ip:3306/my-database</url>`

Reading materials:

- [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) - [Communicating with SQL databases](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development)
- [IBM Worklight Information Center - Adapters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r__adapter_.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time seeing a good reason to use a dataSourceDefinition in the Adapter XML file.  A dataSourceJNDIName is just a little more work to set up, and is the right way to use a DataSource in an adapter.   It separates the runtime details from the development artifacts, it allows for different database servers to be used by different developers or in different environments without changing code, and it gets that database password out of your Adapter XML file.

For an example showing how to configure a JNDI datasource and use it with the Worklight Test server, you can see [this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/jsonstore_revisited_in_worklight_v6_part_1_the_adapter?lang=en)

If you use a dataSourceJNDIName, Your scenario is pretty standard DataSource configuration for whatever app server you are using.